# Showing score as a percentage

Tags: swift

Looking for help to re-express this code.  It currently will show the percentage score for the total amount of questions within the round, so if there are 10 questions in the round it will only show 10% if I answer the first question and get it correct.  I would like the percentage score to show the percentage for the questions answered so if I get the first question correct I'd like it to show 100%, then if I get the second incorrect to show 50% etc

This is the code I have a the moment

```
let percentageScore = score/Double(questionsInCurrentRound.count) * 100
self.percentageScore = percentageScore
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a separate property to keep track of the number of questions answered

```
var questionsAnswered = 0.0
```

And then use it in your calculations

```
questionsAnswered += 1.0
let correctSoFar = score / questionsAnswered
```

Comment: @jon any feedback on this?